# beamer itemize label text alignment

Tags: beamer, itemize

Why does itemize label text spill over onto what I think is called the sidebar(blue horizontal column on the left in the picture)?

I also need to a fix for this problem. The document with this problem uses `\documentclass{beamer}` and uses the outer theme: sidebar.

The following code is responsible for the for the list:

```
 \begin{itemize}
 \item{Problems:}
 \item{Solutions:}
 \end{itemize}
```

[image: The label text is over the sidebar]

Comment: instead of `\item{Problems:}`  and `\item{Solutions:}` write `\item Problems:` and `\item Solutions:`. Or use the `description` environment and square brackets.

Comment: Or `\item[] Problem:`, `\item[] Solution:` ...

Comment: @marmot using a `description` environment instead sounds like a good answer to me. Would you like to write one?

Comment: @samcarter : done. I'll be happy to remove the answer because it might be a duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not specific to beamer. In an `itemize` environment, you may replace the usual bullets (or whatever your document preamble gives you) by some other stuff. However, this stuff will be centered at the same position as the bullets would have been. As a consequence, if this other stuff is too wide, it overshoots on the left. However, this is not a `LaTeX` bug, rather there is a specific environment for this purpose, `description`, which you are supposed to use here. I illustrate this with an MWE, which is highly recommended to be included in questions. I really don't know which theme you are using, so the MWE produces something that looks a bit different.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Problems and Motivation}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Why are marmots so cute?}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{description}
\item[Problems:] Marmots are cute beyond description.
\item[Solutions:]
\end{description}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\section{References}

\end{document}
\endinput
```

[image]